# Can Visual Studio Color/Highlight Methods Adorned With Certain Attributes

Tags: visual-studio-2010, resharper, syntax-highlighting

Is it possible to get Visual Studio (2010) or ReSharper, to render method invocations using different colors using custom Attributes on those methods. For example:

```
[Arrange]
private void ArrangeSomeVariablesAndSetup()
{
    ...
}

[Act]
private void ActOnThoseVariablesOrDoSomethingInteresting()
{
    ...
}

[Assert]
private void AssertThatSomethingHappeningThatWasExpecting()
{
    ...
}
```

Then when calling those methods, Visual Studio should render them in a color based on the Attribute,

```
[Test]
public void MyTest()
{
    ArrangeSomeVariablesAndSetup(); <-- Renders in green
    ActOnThoseVariablesOrDoSomethingInteresting(); <-- Renders in blue
    AssertThatSomethingHappeningThatWasExpecting(); <-- Renders in yellow
}
```

(Attribute names and colors are used purely as an example, also I'm not necessarily restricting this to unit testing)

Comment: Not out of the box, but you can do this yourself. See [Extending the Editor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd885242.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for something that can highlight test methods (as I was), I wrote an extension, [Stay Frosty Method Block Highlighter](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/91cb9cc4-13a3-41fe-a3fe-545786a0ceab) that includes a method block highlighting rule for test methods allowing you to place a translucent box around them based on configurable attributes.

By default, it includes the attributes that would normally appear on an NUnit or MSTest unit test method, however, you can use any attribute you want.  I have it configured to highlight Benchmark classes in my personal configuration.  The only drawback is that "attributed methods" would all be the same (configurable) color.

I'm hoping to extend it over the holidays to allow you to define unlimited numbers of rules/color pairs based on properties of the method -- the data parts are all done, I just need to refactor a couple of bits around rendering.

You've asked specifically about Visual Studio 2010 (though this was back in 2012, so that would have been the most likely version at the time).  The extension supports 2013 and 2015, however, the attribute based method blocks are only supported in Visual Studio 2015 due to its reliance on Roslyn for parsing.  I had back-ported it to the 2013 version, however, the performance of its parser was unacceptable.  Being a weekend project, I didn't have the time to sort it out so that functionality isn't available to prior versions.

Comment: Matthew, your extension is great! Please develop a 2017 version!